# UIPanGestureRecognizer stop calling the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm having trouble to work with UIPanGestureRecognizer as it just calls the selector when I have my finger moving, I want it to keep calling the selector even my finger is standing at the same place.

There are 4 objects on the screen one at the top, one at the right side,  one at the left side and one at the bottom. I have an object at the center of the screen (this is the one I'm moving with the panGesture). When this object touches the others I want it to give me a Log, it works when it touches but if I keep my finger at the same place it stops to give me logs, if I move a little it starts to give me logs again.

Is there anyway I can keep calling the selector even with my finger at the same place?

here is a code example:

```
- (void)moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.limiteDirecional];
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.limiteDirecional];

    CGPoint center = sender.view.center;
    center.y += translation.y;
    int yMin = 0;
    int yMax = self.limiteDirecional.frame.size.height;

    if (center.y < yMin || center.y > yMax )
        return;

    sender.view.center = center;

    center.x += translation.x;
    int xMin = self.limiteDirecional.frame.size.width;
    int xMax = 0;

    if (center.x > xMin || center.x < xMax)
        return;

    sender.view.center = center;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sender.view.frame,self.Top.frame)) {
         NSLog(@"TOP");        
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sender.view.frame,self.Botton.frame)) {
        NSLog(@"BOTTON");
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sender.view.frame,self.Right.frame)) {
        NSLog(@"RIGHT");
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sender.view.frame,self.Left.frame)) {
        NSLog(@" LEFT");
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        sender.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The gesture recognizer, itself, won't do that. You can use timers or `CADisplayLink` or something, but to suggest solutions, it's useful to know what problem you're trying to solve. What problem are you trying to solve by getting notification of changes in touches when there are no changes in touches?

Comment: Right! this is working like a joystick, if you drag the "MainObject" in contact with the "Sensors" it should move my sprite, but if i hold the "MainObject" even if it is touching the "Sensor" it stops to move my sprite! i have to nudge to keep ir moving...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely following the logic of your routine, so I'll provide a generic template of what a solution might look like when you want continuous events in the middle of a gesture, whether the user is moving their finger or not. Hopefully you can adapt this technique for your own purposes.

This uses `CADisplayLink`, which is considered a better technique for animation than the older technique of using a `NSTimer`. To use `CADisplayLink`, though, you need to [add the needed framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html), QuartzCore.framework, to your project, if you haven't already. Also note that in my gesture recognizer, I'm checking the state of a gesture, to know whether we're starting a gesture, in the middle of one, or ending one:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint translationInView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                              action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    // I'm adding to the main view, but add it to whatever you want
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture]; 
}

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    NSLog(@"%s translationInView = %@", __FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGPoint(self.translationInView));

    // Do here whatever you need to happen continuously while the user is in the
    // middle of the gesture, whether their finger is moving or not.
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    self.translationInView = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [self startDisplayLink];

        // Do whatever other initialization stuff as the user starts the gesture
        // (e.g. you might alter the appearance of the joystick to provide some
        // visual feedback that they're controlling the joystick).
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // Do here only that stuff that actually changes as the user is moving their
        // finger in the middle of the gesture, but which you don't need to have
        // repeatedly done while the user's finger is not moving (e.g. maybe the
        // visual movement of the "joystick" control on the screen).
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        [self stopDisplayLink];

        // Do whatever other cleanup you want to do when the user stops the gesture
        // (e.g. maybe animating the moving of the joystick back to the center).
    }
}
@end
```

You can achieve a similar effect if you use `NSTimer`, too. Whatever works better for you.